# Python splitting string. Need help

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to split a string into two different words. I have the following string:

```
test /
```

I want to split it so I can do

```
os.chdir('/')
```

I've tried different splitting techniques but they split by letter so it becomes

```
't','e','s','t', '', '/'
```

Comment: looks like you've tried exactly one "splitting technique" which is `list("test /")` Try looking at the `str.split()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting on a space isn't working? What are you trying to do eventually?

```
'test /'.split(' ')
```

or no parameters at all:

```
tst, path = 'test /'.split()
os.chdir(path)
```

Answer (score 3):

`'test /'.split()` will give you `['test', '/']`. `os.path.split()` is for splitting paths and you might find it useful.